# How convert/adapt ByteObjectHashMap to a JDK Map?

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

Primitive maps don't seem to implement `java.util.Map`.

If I have a function, accepting JDK Map as an argument and now want to pass eclipse collection implementation, for example `ByteObjectHashMap`, what's the easiest way to do that?

it stated [here](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/map/mutable/primitive/package-summary.html), that package `org.eclipse.collections.impl.map.mutable`
contains implementations of the `MutableMap` interface. Primitive are in sub-package of mutable and I expected them to implement `MutableMap`, which, in turn, implements `java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this today is to copy the contents of the `ByteObjectMap` to a `Map<Byte, Object>` using `forEachKeyValue`.

Here is an example converting a `ByteObjectMap<String>` to `Map<Byte, String>`.

```
@Test
public void byteObjectHashMapToMap()
{
    ByteObjectMap<String> map =
            ByteObjectMaps.mutable.<String>empty()
                    .withKeyValue((byte) 1, "1")
                    .withKeyValue((byte) 2, "2")
                    .withKeyValue((byte) 3, "3")
                    .withKeyValue((byte) 4, "4");

    Map<Byte, String> target = new HashMap<>();
    map.forEachKeyValue(target::put);

    Map<Byte, String> expected = Map.of((byte) 1, "1",
            (byte) 2, "2",
            (byte) 3, "3",
            (byte) 4, "4");
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, target);
}
```

**Update:** The Eclipse Collections 11.1 release will have a new method on object and primitive maps called `injectIntoKeyValue`. The following will be possible as a solution once it is released.

```
// Eclipse Collections MutableMap as target
Map<Byte, String> target =
        map.injectIntoKeyValue(Maps.mutable.empty(), MutableMap::withKeyValue);

// JDK Map as target
Map<Byte, String> jdkTarget =
        map.injectIntoKeyValue(new HashMap<>(), 
                (m, k, v) -> {m.put(k, v); return m;});
```

It would be a reasonable contribution from the OSS community to add `Map` views for primitive maps, but this hasn't been done yet. This is probably because it is not a trivial amount of work. When Project Valhalla is available in the JDK, it would be more reasonable for the primitive maps in Eclipse Collections to implement `Map<byte, String>`. This is not possible without primitive specialization over generics in Java.

The package documentation you linked to refers to "Related Packages", but this is clearly something worth clarifying as I can see how it may be confusing. Thank you for pointing this out.